# Is there a connection between "Raised by Wolves" and the Alien universe?

Tags: alien-franchise, raised-by-wolves

In the first season finale of *Raised by Wolves* (which is executive produced by Ridley Scott), Mother is almost killed by a mysterious figure in rags (presumably the same figure seen in the cave under the giant snake skeleton in episode 5), but she kills them first.  When the figure's face is revealed, we see what appears to be

> an Engineer from *Prometheus*

This seems to suggest that *Raised by Wolves* takes place in the Alien universe, except that, as far as I'm aware, I don't think a devastating war on Earth in the 2140s between Mithraists and atheists fits into the Alien chronology.

Has the nature of any connection between the two works been addressed by anyone affiliated with the show?

Comment: I suggest the Posted clues are not helpful. Can you add more?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I'm not clear on what you mean.  Not helpful for what?

Comment: Not helpful for anything to do with the Question… Can you add more, or must we rely on what's been Posted already?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Why not read back through the whole thread, and tell everyone where I went wrong?

Comment: I apologise. The Question title and the spoiler alert distracted me into believing the topic was meant to be a general discussion based on your own view. I'm sorry, I missed the specific request for connections being addressed by anyone affiliated with the show…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According the makers, the easter-eggs found in the production **don't** mean that the two universes are directly connected.

### Aaron Guzikowski - Writer

> Aaron Guzikowski said of the Ridley Scott link: “Obviously, I was
> hugely influenced by all of his work, Prometheus included.”
>
> “There was never any concern with him in terms of how it was going to
> connect to his other stuff,” Aaron explained, “he more wanted to just
> kind of take it for what it was.”
>
> **“It’s a close cousin, and it can kind of sit alongside it,” the
> creator confirmed, “but technically speaking, the mythologies don’t
> link up.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[IS RAISED BY WOLVES CONNECTED TO ALIENS? CREATOR AARON GUZIKOWSKI CONFIRMS SHOW IS “CLOSE COUSIN”](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2020/10/02/is-raised-by-wolves-connected-to-aliens/)</sup></sub>

### Ridley Scott - Producer

> "Interesting question but, no," Scott said, explaining that "the first
> Alien story feels like it may be some time before Raised By Wolves, in
> that the Nostromo was probably financed by an organised global
> economy. Wolves is about post-global war chaos." As far as he's
> concerned, the two projects could connect by some stretch of the
> imagination, but ultimately, they're completely separate. It doesn't
> get more definitive than hearing Ridley Scott put these rumors to
> rest, but this wasn't the only time someone involved with Raised by
> Wolves had to crush so many people's hopes.
>
> <sub><sup>[Ridley Scott Reveals If Raised By Wolves And Alien Are In The Same Universe](https://www.looper.com/255419/ridley-scott-reveals-if-raised-by-wolves-and-alien-are-in-the-same-universe/?utm_campaign=clip)</sup></sub>